# How can I make a settings page in vb which can change the content of the app itself?

Tags: vb.net, settings

I am making an app for companies so they can make a workreport in a blink of an eye by just tapping some togglebuttons and typing some text and the app makes a nicely laid out email and sends it to an Email address

What is need is:
A settings page where I can change the email address which it goes to
The texts of the textblocks and so on.

I just want to make an app which is adaptable for the user.

I know I need to use the isolated storage but I don't really know how to put it in VB so it can change the content of the things needed to be changed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at using My.Settings see this Microsoft Article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(VS.80).aspx once you save the settings from a form text box or other method of input, you can read the settings back on on form load and change the appearance of you application based on the user settings.